# Eclipse can't understand boost and smart pointers?

Tags: c++11, boost-asio, eclipse-cdt

We're using Eclipse CDT for C++ 11 code. I have a class I need to refactor so it can be tested. We're using Google Test/Google Mock to write our unit tests. One class contains a Boost socket, like such:

```
class BoostUser {
    ...
private:
    ...
    boost::asio::ip::udp::socket theSocket;
    ....
}
```

We need to mock calls coming back from the socket, so we decided to change theSocket to a pointer and inject it via the constructor. Since we're using C++ 11, I used a `unique_ptr`. So our member changed to this:

```
class BoostUser {
    ...
private:
    ...
    std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::ip::udp::socket> theSocket = nullptr;
    ....
}
```

I changed all the uses of `theSocket` to use `->` instead of `.`. So calls changed from something like this:

```
theSocket.open(listenEndpoint.protocol());
```

to this:

```
theSocket->open(listenEndpoint.protocol());
```

I compiled it, it compiled fine with no errors. I already had a few unit tests, and they still worked. I started to change the constructor so it took another parameter, the socket for the dependency injection. And that's when I noticed a peculiarity.

All the instances where I changed the dot `.` to the arrow `->` showed as errors. The Eclipse errors reported "Method '[function_name] could not be found'". It showed them for every instance where I made the changes, but, remember, *it compiled with no errors*. If these were real errors, I would've gotten compile errors.

As an experiment, I changed the smart pointers to just a raw pointer, like this:

```
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket* theSocket = nullptr;
```

And Eclipse was perfectly happy with that. It still compiled fine, and Eclipse didn't show any errors. But since this is C++ 11, we're using `unique_ptr` all over the place, and Eclipse is perfectly happy with them. It's just in this instance where Eclipse freaks out over smart pointers, and I can't check in code that uses raw pointers.

Has anyone else run across this problem with Eclipse, smart pointers and Boost classes?

Comment: This is the usual state of affairs for IDEs, unless you have some kind of clang-based completion engine.

Comment: You may be running into [bug 516338](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=516338). It affects `unique_ptr` when using GCC 7 or later with Eclipse Oxygen.1 or older. The bug is fixed in Eclipse Oxygen.2 and later.

Comment: Thanks for the information, guys. Unfortunately, our application doesn't cooperate with .2, so I guess we'll have to live with this error for now. Like I said, it compiles and runs; the error is mostly cosmetic. Maybe .3 will work with our app and we can move past this error.

Comment: Is there a way to suppress the error?